# Elasticsearch template index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a template with specific index pattern, such as 2018-01, 2018-02,2018-03, 2018-xx

The following pattern will meet my requirements:

```
  "index_patterns": ["2018-*"],
```

But it will also cover something like this 2018-01-xxx

I hope it can only cover the index format like this 2018-xx

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: You should be able to define the pattern as [2018-]MM, read here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.4/index-patterns.html. for example check 5.6 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.6/index-patterns.html

Comment: @MarcusHöglund Hej, thanks very much for your answer, this is exactly what I want to have. You can try post a correct answer, so that I can accept it.